# Comparing two Char in C

Tags: c

I have some trouble to compare the content of a message to verify if its correct 
But the problem is that I keep getting segmentation fault.
here is my code :

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char rx_buffer[6];
    rx_buffer[0]='A';
    rx_buffer[1]='1';
    rx_buffer[2]='5';
    rx_buffer[3]='6';
    rx_buffer[4]='8';
    rx_buffer[5]='B';
    if (strcmp(rx_buffer[0],'A')==0 && strcmp(rx_buffer[5],'B')==0)
    {
        printf("Correct Message\n");
    }
 }
```

Comment: A good compiler should at least give you some warnings, read them.

Comment: `strcmp` compares, as its name suggests, _strings_ not `char` values. a string is _an array_ of `char`'s with a nul char at the end (`'\0'` or simply `0`). You're passing a `char` to a function expecting a `char *`. You might also want to initialize `rx_buffer` using a shorter syntax: `unsigned char rx_buffer[] = "A1568B";` then see what the actual size of the array is (it won't be 6: it'll be 7 to accomodate the nul char)

Comment: if I write `rx_buffer[1]=1+'0';` its equivalent to `rx_buffer[1]='1';` ?

Comment: @Mehdi: Yes, in the same way that `rx_buffer[1] = 48 + 1;` is the same as `rx_buffer[1] = '1';` or even `rx_buffer[1] = 'a' - '0';` (`'a'` is 97, `'0'` is 48, 97 -48 = 49 = '1'). Just [look at the ASCII table](http://web.cs.mun.ca/~michael/c/ascii-table.html)

Answer (score 2):

`rx_buffer` doesn't have NUL terminator. So you can't use `strcmp()` on it. Looking at your comparisons, you really wanted to compare chars.
So use `==` operator:

```
if ( rx_buffer[0] == 'A' && rx_buffer[5] == 'B' ) {
     printf("Correct Message\n");
}
```

`strcmp()` is for comparing C-strings (A sewuence of characters terminated by a NUL byte) which is not what you have.

Comment: Thanks a Lot ! but just a question : should I add a NUL terminator ? cause I am working on a serial communication project, and I need to have the correct data sent and received

Comment: No. You don't if you want to compare chars. You *do* if you are comparing strings. E.g. `strcmp(rx_buffer, "B") == 0` Here `rx_buffer` must be NUL (`'\0'`) terminated since `"B"` is a C-string. But `'B'` is a *char*.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing `char` should be done with `==`.

The `strcmp()` calls read past the end of `rx_bytes[]`.